# How to wrapAll element with the same class but different position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Javascript, my HTML list has five items with `.item` class, I want it to `wrapAll` by `ul` element but, when I use the `wrapAll` method of jQuery, so it wraps all `.item` elements with one `ul`, I want it to be a different `ul` separated by other `li` elements like the code below:

```html
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 2</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 6</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 7</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 8</li>
   <li>Item 9</li>
   <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to `wrapAll` the `.item` class like this:

```html
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <ul class='wrap'>
      <li class='item'>Item 2</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <ul class='wrap'>
      <li class='item'>Item 6</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 7</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 8</li>
   </ul>
   <li>Item 9</li>
   <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried this:

```js
$('.item').wrapAll($('<ul/>',{class:'wrap'}));
```

but it goes like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <ul class='wrap'>
      <li class='item'>Item 2</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 3</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 6</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 7</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 8</li>
   </ul>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 9</li>
   <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea could be to select all `li` elements which do not have an `item` class which have an adjacent `li` item with an `.item` class. This essentially will give you all the `li` elements at the start of a group of items. You can then use [`.nextUntil(':not(.item)')`](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) on each starting li to get each `li` element after your first `.item` which has the `.item` class. This gives you all elements but your original starting element, so you need to use [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to add the initial starting element to the collection. You can then wrap this using [`wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```js
$('li:not(.item) + li.item').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(.item)').addBack().wrapAll($('<ul/>',{class:'wrap'}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 2</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 6</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 7</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 8</li>
   <li>Item 9</li>
   <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's amazing how short JQuery solutions can be compared to pure JavaScript.

Comment: @Nanoo haha, yeah, jQuery can be quite powerful sometimes. Although, vanilla JS seems to be slowly catching up. Maybe one day we'll be able to write even smaller code in vanilla without jQuery :P

Answer (score 1):

Here, I made a pure JavaScript solution:

```js
var item = document.querySelectorAll("ul")[0].children;
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
    if (item[i].className == "item") {
        arr.push(item[i]);
        var nextEle = item[i].nextElementSibling;
        if (nextEle.className !== "item") {
            var newGroup = document.createElement("UL");
            newGroup.setAttribute("class", "wrap");
            for (var x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
                console.log(arr[x]);
                newGroup.appendChild(arr[x]);
            }
            nextEle.parentNode.insertBefore(newGroup, nextEle);
            arr = [];
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 2</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 6</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 7</li>
   <li class='item'>Item 8</li>
   <li>Item 9</li>
   <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

This took me a while, but does exactly what you need.